# After Anaconda installation, conda command fails with "ImportError: no module named conda.cli"

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I installed 64 bit Linux version of Anaconda recently (1.8.0-Linux-x86_64). The installation seemed to work fine:

```
$ python 
Python 2.7.5 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Nov  4 2013, 15:30:26)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
##No issues here
```

However if I try any of the conda commands, I get an error:

```
$ conda info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/anaconda/bin/conda", line 3, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ImportError: No module named conda.cli
```

Installation is under my user directory (~/anaconda). I have verified that $PATH contains ~/anaconda/bin. $PYTHONPATH is also set to ~/anaconda/lib.

Any thoughts on what is wrong with the 'conda' command? My searches do not appear to show any one else reporting this error.

Comment: What happens if you unset PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Thanks @asmeurer. unset PYTHONPATH by itself did not work. However, if I also unset PYTHONHOME, it works. Looks like PYTHONHOME was pointing to a different python installation which caused this error.

Comment: Generally with Anaconda, you don't need to set those variables. Just $PATH.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you were installing it, you missed a section. When conda asked you if it can set your .bashrc file, you probably clicked NO. It's a simple fix: fire up your interpreter and add this line:

`export PATH=/home/add your username here/anaconda/bin:$PATH`

Now type `python` into the interpreter and you will see Anaconda 1.8.0 or whatever version you have. You will have to do this each time you start a new interpreter.

Enjoy!

Comment: for me it was : export PATH=/Users/add your username here/anaconda/bin:$PATH, but basically same thing

Comment: This resolved my issue.  Thank you!  I am going to link this to the multiple github issues so that it's easier to find.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, I already have `export PATH="/home/<myusername>/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"` in my .bashrc and it doesn't work. Neither if I go to the folder itself.

Comment: This is now recommended against. See [Conda v4.4 Release Notes](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell).

Answer (score 52):

### Note

If the accepted answer doesn't work, then this answer might help.

### The Cause

According to the official [thread](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2463) on GitHub, this problem happens when there is a change in the python version. In my case, the original anaconda installation is anaconda 3 with `python3.6`. And I installed a new package which updated python to`python3.7` along with some other packages. And this corrupts the anaconda base environment.

### The solution

The solution that works for me is pretty simple... reinstall anaconda.
I don't know if this is the optimal solution, but this what works for me.

- First we need to delete the old installation:

  ```
  rm -rf ~/anaconda3
  rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
  ```
- Then, reinstall Anaconda.
- Finally, update all packages (including conda itself) using:

  ```
  conda update --all
  ```

Now, your anaconda is up-to-date.

Comment: Well, that's scary !

Comment: alternatively, I have started including `python=3.6.5` to my conda install recipes, or whatever the base python version is for the conda I am using. Same result.

Comment: You're removing everything! I can't afford that. I found that copying the `envs` folder in a new conda installation ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66636001/1611927)) fixes the problem.

Answer (score 5):

If anaconda was installed by the root user, a permissions issue could produce the `ImportError: No module named 'conda.cli'` error.

Something like this

`sudo chown -R [username] [anaconda_dir]`

would help in that case.

Alternatively, the conda install could be cloned to another location, such as the user's home directory:

`conda create -n [my_conda_root] --clone=[current_conda_dir]`

But for this to work, you will need at least the read and traverse permissions.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem while downgrading python in a Miniconda3 env. in my Dockerimage. With the Miniconda3-4.5.11-Linux-x86_64.sh installer the initial base python version is 3.7.0; I wanted to downgrade to 3.6.9 and got the "ImportError: no module named conda.cli" error (all in the same layer to reduce the image's size).

I fix this by using the Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh installer instead (which will give you python==3.6.5) and called

```
conda install -y python==3.6.9
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by reinstalling anaconda but keeping the `envs` folder.

So, I moved the old `anaconda3` folder to `anaconda3.old`, I reinstalled anaconda3 at the same location and copied the content of the `anaconda3.old/envs` folder to `anaconda3/envs`. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Anaconda and I found this Solution from somewhere:

Change the content of: /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-5.2.0/bin/conda

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from conda.cli import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

to

```
#!/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
# Before any more imports, leave cwd out of sys.path for internal 'conda shell.*' commands.
# see https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6549
if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1].startswith('shell.') and sys.path and sys.path[0] == '':
    # The standard first entry in sys.path is an empty string,
    # and os.path.abspath('') expands to os.getcwd().
    del sys.path[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from conda.cli import main
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

It happened on Ubuntu (both versions 22.04 and 20), while trying to upgrade Python from the default version that comes with Anaconda 3-5.3.1, e.g. using:

```
conda update python
```

Turns out upgrading Python is a no-no on conda, and I finally had to uninstall anaconda:

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda3 ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
```

And then install a newer version (e.g. Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh, see [here](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-22-04/) on how).

An "interesting" side of this problem is that sometimes Python upgrade happens implicitly as a dependency. For example do not:

```
conda install pandas==1.4.2
pip install pandas==1.4.2
conda install gunicorn
```

Instead - use a higher version of Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I have tried almost every way but none works. The only solution is to force reinstall the conda into your machine so that it would automatically set the path/source into your environment. In, any other case, it ends up with broken conda installation.
So,

1. uninstall anaconda -  `rm -rf ~/anaconda3`
2. uninstall anaconda continuum - `rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum`
3. Force reinstall anaconda - `bash Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -u`

Note: Change .sh file version according to the file you have

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had zsh (zshell) and bash, so the "**conda**" command was working fine in bash but not in the zsh. so, I added the environment variable in the zsh file.

Below were the steps that I took:

1.

```
sudo nano ~/.zshrc
```

2. 

add the below line at the end of the file, make sure to change it based on where you install the anaconda

*export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH*

3.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```