# Anaconda error after install on Windows

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I want to install Anaconda on my x64 Windows machine, and I downloaded the Python 2.7 version 64-bit installer. The installation process looks good.

Then I installed `pip` with `choco` and installed several packages like `zbar`,
however, when I want to try to launch Anaconda, I entered `conda` in Powershell, this is what I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ruiyang\Anaconda2\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import conda.cli
ImportError: No module named conda.cli
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried regular, non-Powershell commandline?

Comment: @pylang, yes, same result.

Comment: This is strange.  Perhaps try installing the Python 3 version.

Answer (score 0):

add anaconda's bin directory to path.
`set path=whatever\anaconda\bin;path;`

Comment: Just checked,`C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda2`, `C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda2\Scripts` and `C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda2\Library\bin` are all in path already. The installer did the job.

Comment: is any `C:\Users\<user>\**Anaconda2\bin**` directory there?

Comment: Nope, there is no such directory. I created one and added it to path, not work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the path variable setting. Quoting from another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825250/after-anaconda-installation-conda-command-fails-with-importerror-no-module-na/20516579#20516579):

> fire up your interpreter and add this line: `export PATH=/Users/add
>   your username here/anaconda/bin:$PATH`
>
> Now type `python` into the interpreter and you will see Anaconda 1.8.0
>   or whatever version you have. You will have to do this each time you
>   start a new interpreter.

Also, note that this might occur when the user name in the path on windows contains a space character. Taken from [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2463#issuecomment-250808090).

Answer (score 0):

Though @devautor's method doesn't work for me, a comment in his [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825250) shows me the correct answer:

Unset both PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME, then my problem is solved.