# ImportError: No module named conda.cli.main while setting up conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

My conda module is in the path '/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin'

In the .bash_profile I added the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin
export PATH
```

Yet when I type

```
conda --version
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/conda", line 4, in <module>
from conda.cli.main import main
ImportError: No module named conda.cli.main
```

Comment: what gives `conda list` in terminal ?

Comment: I get the same error with conda list

Comment: are you able to find the version ? (with `conda -V`), maybe this [comment can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33863470/6655211)

Comment: I tried changing the permissions but it didn't change a thing, still keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I show the ~/.zshrc ( or ~/.bash_profile ) which is the default shell in my Mac.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

After installing Anaconda that is how it looks like. You can try source ~/.bash_profile or ~/zshrc to check if it *base* is activated by Anaconda.

If you want to deactivate *base* look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default)

Answer (score -2):

I followed the process in the continuum documentation and it worked.
Please see: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/linux