# Ubuntu terminal starts with the Anaconda base environment (how to correct that?)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04, gnome-terminal, virtual-environment

I have downloaded and installed the Anaconda distribution for Ubuntu (18.04) from [https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section] conform instructions some weeks ago. Everything worked fine.

Today I updated the packages in the Gnome terminal with:

```
source activate base
conda update --all --yes
conda deactivate
exit
```

Before I did this update, my terminal started with:

```
rene@mylaptop:~$
```

After the update a terminal session starts as follows (with the Anaconda base environment activated):

```
(base) rene@mylaptop:~$
```

How can I prevent this from happening / revert to the previous terminal settings?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

This comes from a similar issue over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default).

Comment: Hi, where is the file in Anaconda dir where we can change the configuration? Thanks

Comment: Hi Salvador, you type that into a terminal window, not in a file. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
deactivate
```

into your console to disable virtualenvs. And double check that your .bashrc doesn't source any virtualenv that you have created.

Edit: Conda requires you to use

```
source deactivate
```

Comment: Thnx. I know that I can use `source deactivate` or `conda deactivate` to quit the (active) virtual environment. In .bashrc I don't see anything related to sourcing virtual environments but when I start a new terminal session, it keeps starting with the Anaconda base environment activated..