# Linux Terminal Problem after installing anaconda

Tags: python, linux, terminal, anaconda

After installing Anaconda every time my linux terminal starts with - 
(base) **username@pcName:**
My question is - why this happening every time?
What is the way to stop the conda and start it when I need that?

When I enter - **$ conda deactivate**; then it acts like before.

Comment: What shell are you using: zsh, bash? Are you using any terminal frameworks like oh-my-zsh, fish, prezto, bash-it? Can you paste .bashrc / .zshrc file?

Comment: After answering I discovered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default

Answer (score 1):

When you install Anaconda or miniconda, you accepted to set itself to PATH and `conda config` has `auto_activate_base`  default to `True`. If you execute

```
conda config --show | grep auto_activate_base
```

You will see the value is True. You can set it to `False` with

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
```

You will still have conda but it will not auto activate your env to `base`

Comment: It appears that this was already asked and correctly answered. I have mark this as dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default