# How to fix Code Runner plugin in VS Code for Miniconda using?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, miniconda, vscode-code-runner

Recently I decide to install Miniconda on my MacBook.

The first problem I faced with was "(base) environment" that Miniconda activated each time as I opened a terminal. So, I disabled this option by command:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

by this advice: [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default)

But I faced with another problem.
Usually, I use a Code Runner plugin for VS Code which allows to run code by ctrl+alt+N hot keys. But after "auto_activate_base" configuration I am getting an error.

I suppose the problem is with the Code Runner plugin that can't activate Python 3 interpreter anymore (by path: "~/miniconda3/bin/python"). Instead of this, it's using Python 2.7 (by path: "/usr/binpython") even when I'm choosing Python 3 interpreter.

```
# For example, if I wrote Python 2.7 code style via ctrl+alt+N I get a correct result
n = 1
print("The number is: %s" % n)
```

> `The number is: 1`

```
# But, Python3 style code return an error
n = 1
print(f"The number is: {n}")
```

> `File "<path to file>
>       print(f"The number is: {n}")
>                                 ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Earlier, when I used an Anaconda distribution the Code Runner plugin worked fine.
How can I get similar behavior with Miniconda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by setting `code-runner.executorMap` parameter which defines a path to Python-interpreter by default.

Need to edit "setting.json" file in VS Code the next way:

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 14,

    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "~/miniconda3/bin/python"
    }

}
```