# tcl-tk (tkinter) not installing via Homebrew pyenv on MacOS Mojave

Tags: python, tcl, homebrew, macos-mojave, pyenv

If I do this on MacOS Mojave in Homebrew:

```
$ brew install tcl-tk
$ brew install pyenv
$ pyenv install 3.7.4
$ pyenv global 3.7.4
$ python -m tkinter -c 'tkinter._test()'
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/craign/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/Users/craign/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/Users/craign/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/Users/craign/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I've been searching for days, and have tried various solutions such as [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1375) but without luck so far. Any ideas why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never got this to work. I spent a ton of time on [this page](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1375#issuecomment-533182043) as well as a number of other sites, and tried everything. It seems that Homebrew Python and Tcl-Tk are at this time not out of the box the same version, and it's a common issue. What I did end up doing was to install both pyenv and anaconda side by side as per the excellent instructions of @Simba [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640272/how-can-i-install-anaconda-aside-an-existing-pyenv-installation-on-osx), and using Anaconda my Tcl-Tk commands are working fine. Posting here so that others don't fall down this rabbit hole, or if they do and find a solution, it would be wonderful to know.

Comment: I actually managed to get this working on a laptop, but then following the exact same instructions didn't work on iMac I have.

Answer (score 6):

Here is **step by step guide** to make IDLE and `tkinter` work:

1. install `tcl-tk` with Homebrew. In shell run `brew install tcl-tk`
2. in shell run `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
3. reload shell by quitting `Terminal` app or run `source ~/.zshrc`
4. after reloaded check that `tck-tk` is in `$PATH`. Run `echo $PATH | grep --color=auto tcl-tk`. As the result you should see your $PATH contents with `tcl-tk` highlighted
5. now we run three commands from Homebrew's output from step #1

   1. in shell run `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib"`
   2. in shell run `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include"`
   3. in shell run `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig"`
6. if you have your Python version already installed with `pyenv` then uninstall it with `pyenv uninstall <your python version>`. E.g. `pyenv uninstall 3.8.2`
7. set environment variable that will be used by `python-build`. In shell run `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'"`
   *Note: in future use `tck-tk` version that actually installed with Homebrew. At the moment of posting `8.6` was the actual*
8. finally install Python with `pyenv` with `pyenv install <version>`. E.g. `pyenv install 3.8.2`

**Test**

1. in shell run `pyenv global <verion that you've just installed>`
2. now check IDLE. In shell run `idle`. You should see IDLE window without any warnings and "text printed in red".

[image: IDLE window run from Terminal. No warnings]

3. now check `tkinter`. In shell run `python -m tkinter -c "tkinter._test()"`. You should see test window like on the image:

[image: tkinter test window]

That's it!

**My environment:**

check this is something went wrong executing steps above:

1. macOS Catalina
2. `zsh` (included in macOS Catalina) = **"shell" above**
3. Homebrew (installed with instructions from Homebrew official website)
4. `pyenv` (installed with Homebrew and PATH updated according to `pyenv` official readme from GitHub)
5. Python `3.8.x` - `3.9.x` (installed with `pyenv install <version>` command)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I tried to install `tkinter` through pyenv. Although @Dribbler answer was helpful to find out that anaconda is more compatible, when I followed @Simba instructions, I still got an error that says that `there is no conda command`.
Finally, I was able to fix it using the following in case someone has the same problem and still want to stick with `pyenv`.

**The Fix**

1. I followed @nickolay instructions to install `tkinter` and set the path the proper way.
2. Then, I installed anaconda3-2020.07 using the `pyenv install anaconda3-2020.07` command.
3. Because I am using pyenv python 3.8.6 **globally**: I navigated to the folder I want to use tkinter and used the `anaconda3-2020.07` **locally** by utilizing the command `pyenv local anaconda3-2020.07`to use this version of pyenv in that specific folder. It ran without errors!

[image]

**Note:** I am using the following script in the `.bash_profile` to trigger the virtualenv automatically when cd the desired directory

```sh
# manage python version using pyenv
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

# add pyenv virtualenv
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```