# Does pyproject.toml need to exist in the target directory when using poetry to install a local package?

Tags: python, pipenv, python-poetry

I have a local package, "mypackage", inside a venv environment. I successfully ran `poetry install` and I'm able to import it into Python sessions started inside of the same virtual env. Now I want to use mypackage in other projects and environments on my machine, specifically a pipenv environment setup for "myproject".

I followed the steps here: [Install the latest version of my package from working directory into my local environment using Python's poetry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64829418/11080806) But that leads to: `Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in C:\Users\jonathan.biemond\PycharmProjects\myproject or its parents` Do I need to have a pyproject.toml file in my project directory to import mypackage? myproject is not a package, just a local, undistributed project, so I don't have dependencies to maintain...

Here are my steps to setup mypackage:

1. Create venv for mypackage: `python -m venv`
2. `pip install poetry`
3. `poetry init` from mypackage directory to create pyproject.toml for mypackage
4. `poetry install`

Now I can use mypackage in the same virtual environment it was created in.

But I also want to use it in another virtual environment. Here are my steps to import mypackage:

1. `pipenv install numpy` from myproject directory to create environment (and install numpy)
2. Install poetry: `(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | py -`
3. Install mypackage: `poetry install mypackage`

Comment: You do not need Poetry to use a library created/managed by Poetry. -- It seems like the project that uses your Poetry-created library is itself managed by Pipenv, so use Pipenv to add this dependency on you `mylibrary`, no need to install Poetry if you already Pipenv.

Comment: But I do need a `setup.py` file to install a package using pip or pipenv. Which I don't have because mypackage is managed by Poetry. So I follow the steps here: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/discussions/1135#discussioncomment-145756 But same problem.

Comment: I am very confused. I think you probably should edit your question and rewrite with less confusing details. -- You do not need a `setup.py`, why do you suddenly mention `setup.py` out of nowhere? -- It seems to me like you have 2 "projects" in play. One project is the development of your library `mypackage`. This project and its virtual environment is "managed by "Poetry". And the other is `myproject` which is some kind of application maybe or at least a project that uses/dependes on `mylibrary` and is managed by Pipenv (including its virtual environment). Is that right?

Comment: You're correct, I don't have a good understanding of managing dependencies and packaging pythons and am not sure what details to include. --That's right I have 2 projects. `mypackage` is managed by Poetry, but the virtual environment is created/managed by `venv`. And yes `myproject` is managed by Pipenv. Both are locally on my machine. -- I mention `setup.py` because, I understood your suggestion to install `mypackage` using pipenv and pip/pipenv requires a package to have a `setup.py` file.

Comment: From your `myproject`, you should instruct Pipenv to add your `mypackage` as a dependency, I guess it seems it could be something like `pipenv install path/to/mylibrary`, or at least that is what I would try if I were in your case.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you! When I first tried that it failed, which I misinterpreted as meaning `mylibrary` needed to have a `setup.py` file. But I actually just pointed it to the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In fact, as sinoroc points out in the comments:

> You do not need Poetry to use a library created/managed by Poetry.

Instead use pip or pipenv to install `mypackage` to `myproject` with:

`pipenv install path/to/mylibrary`