# How should pyenv interface with Conda environments?

Tags: python, conda, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I saw on the Internet that we should use `pyenv` to avoid affecting the system Python. I know we can use `pyenv-virtualenv` to create a virtual environment. However, Conda can also be used to create virtual environments. I'm confused up to this point. Should I install `pyenv` and Miniconda separately, or should I install Miniconda under `pyenv`?

Currently, I have installed pyenv and miniforge on my Mac with Homebrew. I mainly use Conda to create my virtual environments, but this makes pyenv seems kinda useless.

Edit:

So in the beginning, I also saw this post: [What is the difference between pyenv, virtualenv, anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217545/what-is-the-difference-between-pyenv-virtualenv-anaconda), comparing the differences. I thought these two different things shoudl be used separately until I saw the github page of pyenv-virtualenv: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv. In the last section, it says something like

> You can manage conda environments by conda create as same manner as standard Anaconda/Miniconda installations. To use those environments, you can use pyenv activate and pyenv deactivate

People also mentioned conflicts between `conda` and `pyenv`. [How can I install Anaconda aside an existing pyenv installation on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640272/how-can-i-install-anaconda-aside-an-existing-pyenv-installation-on-osx). So I'm confused that if I should install conda under pyenv or install them separately.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad. I would suggest googling around a bit, to see what the differences are. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217545/what-is-the-difference-between-pyenv-virtualenv-anaconda) for example.

Comment: Hi @simon_mac and thanks for the question! I adjusted it to be more concretely about Conda-pyenv interaction, as in the first form it was rather broad. Please feel free to adjust the question further if you think the intent can be better expressed. The question could also be further improved by providing the *source* of what you "*saw on the Internet*".

Comment: Thank you @merv. This is the first time I made a post on stackoverflow. I'm not familiar with these concepts as well, so I apologize for the mess.