# Installing anaconda with pyenv, unable to configure virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda, pyenv

I am using pyenv to manage python installations and virtual environments - and I would like anaconda to be one such installation, and to be able to create virtual environments using anaconda python. Using `pyenv install anaconda3-2019.03` successfully installs and I can activate the version with `pyenv global anaconda3-2019.03`:

```
SamLee-PC:~ max$ pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.10
  2.7.10/envs/flask_tutorial
* 3.7.4 (set by /Users/max/.pyenv/version)
  3.7.4/envs/learning_python
  3.7.4/envs/microblog
  3.7.4/envs/stocktool
  3.7.4/envs/test1
  anaconda3-2019.03
  anaconda3-2019.03/envs/datsci
  datsci
  flask_tutorial
  learning_python
  microblog
  stocktool
  test1
SamLee-PC:~ max$ pyenv which python
/Users/max/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/bin/python
SamLee-PC:~ max$ pyenv global anaconda3-2019.03
(anaconda3-2019.03) SamLee-PC:~ max$ pyenv which python
/Users/max/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2019.03/bin/python
(anaconda3-2019.03) SamLee-PC:~ max$ pyenv which conda
/Users/max/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2019.03/bin/conda
```

(I do not know why the python version is added to the command prompt only with the anaconda installation)

When I creat a new virtual environment (`pyenv virtualenv anaconda3-2019.03 datsci`), it appears to work as intended:

```
SamLee-PC:~ max$ pyenv which python
/Users/max/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/bin/python
SamLee-PC:~ max$ cd code/linkedin/datsci
(datsci) SamLee-PC:datsci max$ pyenv which python
/Users/max/.pyenv/versions/datsci/bin/python
(datsci) SamLee-PC:datsci max$
```

This is the same relative location returned returned by `pyenv which python` in my other virtual environments, which all work properly.

**The problem** is that the python version that gets run in the virtual environment doesn't have access to all of anaconda's packages:

```
(datsci) SamLee-PC:datsci max$ anaconda-navigator
pyenv: anaconda-navigator: command not found

The `anaconda-navigator' command exists in these Python versions:
  anaconda3-2019.03

(datsci) SamLee-PC:datsci max$
```

though it does if I activate the python installation manually:

```
SamLee-PC:~ max$ pyenv global anaconda3-2019.03
(anaconda3-2019.03) SamLee-PC:~ max$ anaconda-navigator
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
/Users/max/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2019.03/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/conda_api.py:1364: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  data = yaml.load(f)
2019-09-21 14:03:38,666 - ERROR download_api._download:234
Invalid url https://www.anaconda.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Webinar20-20Three20Ways20to20Move20your20Data20Science20Projects20to20Production.png
#anaconda navigator GUI opens
```

(oddly, the python version that `datsci` points to *does* seem to recognize conda:

```
(datsci) SamLee-PC:datsci max$ pyenv which python
/Users/max/.pyenv/versions/datsci/bin/python
(datsci) SamLee-PC:datsci max$ conda
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...

conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications, environments and packages.

...
```

The problem is that, as I understand it, activating the python version this way whenever I want anaconda means that I only have access to one version of anaconda python - defeating the purpose of using it in a virtual environment.

One more piece of the puzzle - I noticed that for my other virtual environments, `~/.pyenv/versions/name-of-virtualenv` contains a file `pyvenv.cfg`, which contains e.g. the following:

```
  1 home = /Users/max/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/bin                                                                   
  2 include-system-site-packages = false
  3 version = 3.7.4
```

There was no such file in `~/.pyenv/versions/datsci`, so I added one:

```
  1 home = /Users/max/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2019.03/bin                                                       
  2 include-system-site-packages = false
  3 version = anaconda3-2019.03
```

to no avail.

FWIW the contents of that directory are:

```
(anaconda3-2019.03) SamLee-PC:datsci max$ pwd
/Users/max/.pyenv/versions/datsci
(anaconda3-2019.03) SamLee-PC:datsci max$ ls
bin     conda-meta  include     lib     pyvenv.cfg  share       ssl
(anaconda3-2019.03) SamLee-PC:datsci max$
```

I wonder if I have the wrong contents in the `pyvenv.cfg` file for datsci...but I am at a loss.

I really like the way pyenv works, and I would like to continue using it. Is there a way to configure anaconda to behave properly under pyenv?

## Update:

I uninstalled my pyenv-managed anaconda and did a fresh install as per Simba's recommendation. Now by default pyenv determines the active python installation, and I can activate conda with `conda activate base`:

```
Maxs-MacBook-Air:~ max$ which python
/Users/max/.pyenv/shims/python
Maxs-MacBook-Air:~ max$ conda activate base
(base) Maxs-MacBook-Air:~ max$ which python
/Users/max/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) Maxs-MacBook-Air:~ max$
```

**However** after creating a new conda environment with `conda create --name datsci`, the new conda environment does not seem to activate properly:

```
Maxs-MacBook-Air:~ max$ conda activate datsci
(datsci) Maxs-MacBook-Air:~ max$ which python
/Users/max/.pyenv/shims/python
```

What am I missing?

Here are the contents of my `.bash_profile`:

```
  1 export PATH="/Users/max/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  2 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
  3 eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
  4 
  5 # >>> conda initialize >>>
  6 # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
  7 __conda_setup="$('/Users/max/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
  8 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  9     eval "$__conda_setup"
 10 else
 11     if [ -f "/Users/max/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
 12         . "/Users/max/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
 13     else
 14         export PATH="/Users/max/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
 15     fi
 16 fi
 17 unset __conda_setup
 18 # <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Is it important that I duplicate the if statement found in Simba's `.bash_profile?`

## Update 2:

Problem solved, I had to install python in the new environment.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Personal recommendation: Don't use `pyenv` to install Anaconda or Miniconda.

Both `pyenv` and `conda` are able to manage different python environments. The `anaconda` installed by `pyenv` should only **serves as a Python interpreter**. Python environment creation from anaconda installed by `pyenv` is still handled by `pyenv virtualenv` but not `conda env create`.

I've been using these two tools together. It turns out the best solution is to install `conda`, `pyenv` separately, and manage their virtual environments separately as well.

1. alway initialize `pyenv`
2. only expose command `conda` but don't activate any environment

#### Detail

Install `pyenv`.

Install Anaconda or Miniconda normally, NOT by `pyenv install`.

Make sure the `pyenv` and `conda` commands are available in an interactive shell.

Initialize `pyenv` by putting following content into shell init file (`.bashrc` for Bash, `.zshrc` for ZSH).

```sh
# Put the content into ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile for Bash,
# .zshrc for ZSH

# you may need to add dir of command `pyenv` into PATH,
# if command pyenv is not available yet

if command -v pyenv &>/dev/null; then
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
if command -v pyenv-virtualenv &>/dev/null; then
    eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
fi
```

Expose command `conda` but don't activate any environment, even the `base` environment. Execute the following commands in your shell.

```sh
# Run the content in the shell

# init conda, the following command write scripts into your shell init file automatically
conda init

# disable init of env "base"
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Note: After this setup, the default python is the one set by `pyenv global`. Use `pyenv` and `conda` to manage environments separately.

Examples of managing virtual environments.

```sh
# virtual environments from pyenv
pyenv install 3.6.9
pyenv virtualenv 3.6.9 new-env
pyenv activate new-env
pyenv deactive
# You can also use `pyenv local`


# virtual environments from conda
conda env create new-env python=3.6
conda env list
conda activate new-env
conda deactivate
```

Default env location for `pyenv` is `~/.pyenv/versions`.

Default env location for `conda`, check output from `conda info`.

#### References

- [pyenv installation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation)
- [pyenv virtualenv installatoin](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#installation)
- [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57974390/5101148)

Comment: thanks for this! `conda config --set auto_activate_base false` did the trick for me.

Comment: the second `if` should probably look for the command `pyenv virtualenv` (no hyphens)

Comment: @SaverioGuzzo You misunderstood it. `pyenv virtualenv` is not one command, it's command `pyenv` calling its sub command `virtualenv`. `pyenv virtualenv foo` calls `pyenv` and pass `virtualenv foo` as arguments to it. `pyenv` accepts these args, dispatches the calling to command/script `pyenv-virtualenv`, and pass `foo` as an argument. Basically, `pyenv-virtualenv foo` will be called at last. That's how `pyenv` works.

Comment: pyenv-virtualenv advertises (on their GitHub page https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) that it can manage conda environments. why do you prefer to keep them separate?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions.  Otherwise quite some time  should be spent to figure out how to run pyenv and conda in a non-conflicting seamless  way on the same machine.

Comment: Why should the base environment not be activated?

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation and recipe, I was managing miniconda with pyenv and it was a nightmare

Comment: Thanks for your post @Simba. Would you elaborate more on installing `conda` separately?  What are the pros and cons? Some experts advise installing it with `pyenv`. For example: [Use pyenv and virtual environments to manage Python complexity](https://www.wrighters.io/use-pyenv-and-virtual-environments-to-manage-python-complexity/). As Wouter van Amsterdam indicated `pyenv-virtualenv` shows examples where `conda` was installed through `pyenv`. Thanks