# pyenv versions doesnt show anything after installing other version of python on mac big sur

Tags: python, homebrew, pyenv, macos-big-sur

Why doesn't it show my python version installations?

```
% pyenv versions 
* system (set by /Users/axilaris/.pyenv/version)
```

I know I have Python 3.6 (that comes with Big Sur) and 3.8 and 3.9 (I have installed using Python .pkg installer - https://www.python.org/downloads/)

I have installed pyenv using:

```
brew install pyenv
```

UPDATE (here are existing python I found existing in my mac):

```
% pwd
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
% ls -al
total 0
drwxrwxr-x   6 root  wheel  192 Jan 11 14:18 .
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel  192 Jan 11 14:18 ..
drwxrwxr-x  10 root  admin  320 Nov  8  2017 3.6
drwxrwxr-x  10 root  admin  320 Jan  2 18:24 3.8
drwxrwxr-x  11 root  admin  352 Jan 11 14:18 3.9
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jan 11 14:18 Current -> 3.9
% python -V  
Python 2.7.16
% python3 -V
Python 3.9.1


in another location

% ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel  224 Jan  1  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel  160 Jan  1  2020 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jan  1  2020 2.3 -> 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jan  1  2020 2.5 -> 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jan  1  2020 2.6 -> 2.7
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  352 Jan  1  2020 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jan  1  2020 Current -> 2.7
% pwd
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

Comment: I have to same issue... asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637759/pyenv-not-picking-up-other-python-installations)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65662360/mac-os-big-sur-python-version-2-7-16-appears-eventhough-it-doesnt-exist-other <-- I also have something related here. I'll follow yours as well. I would like to know what is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`pyenv versions` only shows versions installed and managed *by pyenv*

MacOS comes with Python on its own (the `system` one), but if you use `brew install python3`, for example, or download from python.org, then `pyenv` will not "list" that.

Comment: how can I get all the installed python "to be" managed by pyenv ? I have updated a bit, and I know there are several versions of python existing.

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't such a way

Comment: I spent over an hour troubleshooting issues with pyenv using ChatGPT and in 20 seconds I found the answer here. Thanks, OneCricketeer, for reminding me that people are still better than an AI.

Comment: @Mike I'm sure many of my answers have been duplicated there, in some form :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to install with pyenv like this, for example: `pyenv install 3.7.4`. Then it will list those Python installations, as well. I'm on Big Sur, and it's working fine for me. Best of luck!