# How are python version 2 and version 3 organized ? I have trouble after brew uninstall python@, I want to reinstate/repair

Tags: python, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I did on my mac big sur:

```
brew uninstall python@2
```

and then, I tried to check the version of python I have

```
% pwd
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
% ls -al
total 0
drwxrwxr-x   6 root  wheel  192 Jan 11 14:18 .
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel  192 Jan 11 14:18 ..
drwxrwxr-x  10 root  admin  320 Nov  8  2017 3.6
drwxrwxr-x  10 root  admin  320 Jan  2 18:24 3.8
drwxrwxr-x  11 root  admin  352 Jan 11 14:18 3.9
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jan 11 14:18 Current -> 3.9
% python -V  
Python 2.7.16
% python3 -V
Python 3.9.1


in another location

% ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel  224 Jan  1  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel  160 Jan  1  2020 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jan  1  2020 2.3 -> 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jan  1  2020 2.5 -> 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jan  1  2020 2.6 -> 2.7
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  352 Jan  1  2020 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 Jan  1  2020 Current -> 2.7
% pwd
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

Why does Python 2.7.16 still appears and it is not defaulting to python 3.9.1 ? How do I clean this up? And where is Python 2.7.16 located, I cant find it link anywhere. I tried this as well and it doesnt show any version info.

```
% pyenv versions                                           
* system (set by /Users/axilaris/.pyenv/version)
```

I am having loads of trouble with Mac OS Big Sur. How do I set the python links correctly and do necessary python cleanups in my mac now ?

Comment: Macs have Python 2 builtin by default. When you install `python@3` (I assume through `brew`), they have instructions on how to link it in the installation log — have you done that? It's `brew link python@3.9` or something, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: I ran Update Shell Profile.command that comes after the installation.  https://gist.github.com/axilaris/0dc2c05eff34324f98e4e627c12b0605. it says: "This script will update your shell profile when the 'bin' directory
of python is not early enough of the PATH of your shell."

Comment: Sorry, my Mac's too old for Big Sur so I can't reproduce :( But it works fine on Catalina after running the linking command.

Comment: what is the difference /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions and /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions

Comment: FYI from what I understand pyenv will only show the versions installed with pyenv + the system one... I only use pyenv for installing new versions of Python because I don't want to mess with the system version(s)