# can't use conda after reinstall anaconda in another directory

Tags: anaconda, installation

I am using ubuntu terminal in tcsh shell. Since there are no memory, I uninstal anaconda by rm -rf it in one director, which is '/glade/u/home/lixujin/anaconda3'. And then I install it in another directory, which is '/glade/work/lixujin/anaconda3'.

After I follow the instruction to install it, I test it by type conda list. Then I get information like this 
`/glade/u/home/lixujin/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh: No such file or directory.` , which is my old install directory.

So, I guess there still are some environment variables I need to change. But I don't where I should modify.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: follow complete instruction for downloading conda in ubuntu.
https://github.com/Nitish1206/conda_setup_for_ubuntu you might be missing source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conda` need to be initialized in the shell init script, `~/.tcshrc` for tcsh.

1. Add `/glade/work/lixujin/anaconda3/condabin` into your `PATH`. (I mean `anaconda3/condabin` but not `anaconda3/bin`.)
2. Open a **new** interactive tcsh shell, run `conda init`.

After above commands, `conda` will write init script into your `.tcshrc` and `codna` will work properly.

#### Caveat

Add `/path/to/anaconda3/condabin` but not `bin` into `PATH`. That's a big **change introduced in `conda` 4.6**.

[Activation script initialization fron `conda` 4.6 release log](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/)

> Conda 4.6 adds extensive initialization support so that more shells than ever before can use the new `conda activate` command. For more information, read the output from `conda init –help` We’re especially excited about this new way of working, because removing the need to modify `PATH` makes Conda much less disruptive to other software on your system.

In the old days, when the `conda-installation/bin` directory is added into `PATH`, the default Python environment from "base" is activated by default. After `conda` 4.6, `conda` related commands are separated into `condabin`, which makes it possible to expose `conda` command only without activating the Python from "base" environment.

#### References

- [Get started with conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html)
- [Conda 4.6 Release](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/)
- [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57974390/5101148)

Comment: @lixujin Read my answer carefully. I mean `anaconda3/condabin` but not `anaconda/bin`. After that, there's another step to be done.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

if you still had a problem open the file .bashrc (hidden file), located in the home directory, runs codes every time a new terminal is opened. and then add it

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I use a tcsh shell. And I have already added `setenv PATH        "/glade/u/home/lixujin/work/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` in .cshrc. But it still doesn't work.