# Required to run "source .bash" for a new terminal for the correct python path

Tags: python, bash

I have a strange problem with ipython path. When I open a terminal and type
`which ipython`, I get 
`"/Users/test/anaconda3/bin/ipython"`

which messes up with some of my definitions. Regardless, when I run `source .bash_profile` it changes the path to `"/usr/local/bin/ipython"`. 
Basically, everytime I open a tab, I have to run `source .bash_profile` for the correct path.
These are the contents of my bash file and I have not seen a problem like this before.

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/test/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/test/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/test/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/test/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
PYTHONPATH="/Users/test/Documents/heasoft-6.25/x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0/lib/python"
PYTHONPATH="/Users/test/anaconda3/lib/python3.7:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Comment: Adding the same lines to `~/.bashrc` probably should solve your problem.

Comment: it is the same as .bashrc. It won't help. I tried it anyways and no luck.

Comment: Try moving `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` to the end of your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: I am unsure about code by anaconda. Probably, when your bash_profile is ran the very first time i.e. anaconda puts its python path on top of your desired one. But the second time you source it, due to `if [ -f "/Users/test/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]`, it finds it is already in path and doesn't make any changes. So your path has `/usr/local/bin` on top in that case.

Comment: yes, thank you so much. You were right. The ```if``` loop was the issue. I moved all my path definitions after the if loop. Now, it has anaconda path plus the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug or a problem. It's an expected behavior that `/Users/test/anaconda3/bin/ipython` prioritize `/usr/local/bin/ipython`.

This is because the "base" Python environment from Anaconda/Miniconda, `/Users/test/anaconda3/bin`, is prepended in the `PATH`.

The following content in your `.bash_profile` is the `conda` initialization script, which makes sure command `conda` works properly.

```
# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
...
# <<< conda init <<<
```

And one of the default behavior of initialization of `conda` is to expose its "base" Python environment.

All you need to do is disable the activation of "base" Python environment.

#### Solution

1. Remove the above `conda` initialization script in `.bash_profile`. Replace it with

   ```sh
   # only expose the `conda` command but not the "base" environment
   export PATH="/Users/test/anaconda3/condabin:$PATH"
   ```
2. Disable activation of the "base" Python env by running following command in a **new** interactive shell.

   ```sh
   # re-generate init script
   conda init
   # disable activation of "base" environment
   conda config --set auto_activate_base false
   ```

#### References

- [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57974390/5101148)
- [Activation script initialization: `conda init`](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/)

Comment: Thank you so much.  @Mihir suggested along similar lines, but thanks for the descriptive answer.