# Git bash opens in anaconda base environment by default (Windows 10)

Tags: conda, git-bash

I added anaconda to my PATH because I wanted git bash to be able to utilize conda commands and I noticed that git bash opens in the base environment on startup by default. How do I make it stop activating on startup?

What git bash opens with:

[image: 1]]

My PATH variables:

[image: 2]]

Comment: Since this is not a programming question and more on configuration, so you're question might suited for Unixstackexchange or superuser.com

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default) Also, don't manipulate PATH manually (recommended against since Conda v4.4), instead [use `conda init`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918).

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.