# What is Meaning of this command 'conda config --set auto_activate_base False or True' for anaconda in linux

Tags: conda

I installed anaconda on my Linux system while installing it asked for `conda config --set auto_activate_base False or True` setting.
If I set `conda config --set auto_activate_base True` it add base() `(base) vijay@vijay-HP-Notebook:~$` before username in terminal and if set `conda config --set auto_activate_base False` it removes the base(). What is actual meaning of this. Should I set it to `True` or `False`.

Comment: Top 3 Google Search results for "conda config --set auto_activate_base": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default, https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8211, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026383/why-does-base-appear-in-front-of-my-terminal-prompt. Why ask a new question on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you install the *anaconda* or *miniconda* scientific python distribution, you install a special isolated environment with preinstalled python interpreter and other packages (e.g. the package/environment manager conda and others). This isolated environment is called the `base` environment.

When `auto_activate_base` is true the base environment is activated automatically whenever you start a new shell. This means that the anaconda's or miniconda's python interpreter is your new default python interpreter and all tools installed into the base environment are automatically available in the shell.

If you do not want this behavior (e.g. you would like to use the system's python interpreter by default) you can set `auto_activate_base` to false. You can then manually switch to the `base` environment by typing `conda activate base`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was little bit confuse about why there is base() it was annoying me.