# Running pipenv with specific conda env?

Tags: python, conda, pipenv, python-venv

I have a conda environment, `cenv`. While activated, I've installed `pipenv` via:

`(cenv) % conda install -c conda-forge pipenv`

I created a `pipenv` env in a repo by installing a package I'll need, in this case the GDAL bindings, `gdal`:

`(cenv) %  pipenv install gdal`

All good so far. Now when I want to launch the `pipenv` shell to see if my installation worked in python, I run:

`(cenv) % pipenv shell`

And I get:

```
Launching subshell in virtual environment…
 . /home/<user>/.venvs/cenv-<scramble>/bin/activate
(base) %  . /home/<user>/.venvs/cenv-<scramble>/bin/activate
(modis_lst) (base) %
```

So I get kicked out of the `(cenv)` `conda` env and put in the system `conda` env, `(base)`, which is not set up how I need. I can deactivate the `(base)` env, and activate the `(cenv)` env, but I'm looking for a better solution. Because I'm not sure I could use `pipenv run` in this way.

How can I start a `pipenv` shell or `run pipenv` while choosing the `conda` env I want to use? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [this related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54560785/11417211) solves my problem. Needed to run `conda config --set auto_activate_base false` to disable - you guessed it - auto-activation of the `(base)` env. Now I can run `pipenv shell`/`pipenv run` and the `pipenv` env will launch within the currently activated `conda` env.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to create new virtual env in conda using pipenv?
If it true, you no need to use pipenv. In anaconda navigator, choose Environment tab, create a new one. Done.
If not, please explain, I want to know a new thing.

Comment: I have a scenario where I want to use `pipenv` in the typical way with other tools in the particular `conda` env. I'm just using `pipenv` for sake of consistency with other projects, on a system I don't normally use. This is a case where just the `conda` env should be fine by itself, you're right. I found a related question that solves this problem, included the link as an answer if you're interested.