# (venv) (base) both active on a python project, how do I get into venv only?

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

So I am using vscode with conda (for a django project), and trying to activate my virtual environment named "venv".
And it goes from:

```
(base) C:\Users\User\Desktop\pfa-master\pfa-master\venv\Scripts> .\activate
```

to something like this:

```
(venv) (base) C:\Users\User\Desktop\pfa-master\pfa-master\venv\Scripts>
```

And if I try to find out Python version, it shows error like this:

```
(venv) (base) C:\Users\User\Desktop\pfa-master\pfa-master>which python
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Note: I have Python in environment variables for anaconda.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: activate is not a valid anaconda command, you should use `conda activate venv` instead

Comment: Maybe try and use the `deactivate` command to exit the virtual environments? You might need to do this twice to exit both virtual environments, and then just activate your `venv` environment separately

Comment: Also if you want to know the Python installation directory on Windows, you can do it by opening a `cmd` terminal (if you're currently in a Powershell terminal you can use the command `start cmd` to do this) and use the command `where python`, this will print out all Python installation locations on your system path. If you want to just know which version of Python is currently the default, use `python --version`

Comment: if you want to work in the environment you can use both,its highly encouraged to use an environment..
but i prefer without env

Comment: If you want to prevent Conda from auto-activating, then possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54429210/570918

Answer (score 8):

You need to deactivate Conda. In terminal, `conda deactivate` should get rid of (base). When you want to reactivate Conda, `conda activate`.

Answer (score 6):

You have two virtual environments active.

**conda** and **virtualenv** are both package manager and environment management system :

- (base) is from conda : https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/
- (venv) is from virtualenv : https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

If you want to use (venv) only, you need to deactivate conda : `conda deactivate`

If you want to use (base) only, you need to delete the venv directory from your repository :
`sudo rm -rf venv`. *Command differs because you are using Windows.*

Answer (score 1):

first you can use `activate` to activate venv, and then use `conda deactivate` to deactivate (base).

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `python -V` to find the installed python version and `pip -V` to get the current pip version.

Comment: Thanks. But my main concern is getting into the virtual environment 'venv' and why does it show 'base' there?

Comment: Well you tried the which command, it does not work on windows afaik

Answer (score 0):

if you have anaconda in your environmental PATH, try `activate venv`. Also, try restarting VScode sometimes it glitches.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
python --version
```

Comment: can you expand on your answer? It's good to explain why someone needs to use a certain command.