# conda: pip fails in venv due to SSL verification problems - how to make it work as in base environment

Tags: python, ssl, pip, miniconda, zscaler

If I create a virtual environment using `venv` and run pip I get `WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL,...` although it works in the base environment.
If the base and virtual environment are active (was by accident similar to [(venv) (base) both active on a python project, how do I get into venv only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64207964/venv-base-both-active-on-a-python-project-how-do-i-get-into-venv-only)) it works without any complaints.

I sit behind a proxy server (Zscaler) so I have to point to the root certificate of the proxy. I added that as a comment in https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9746#issuecomment-767043072.
I added the package pyOpenSSL but it did not resolve the issue.

I suspect that is related is caused by the proxy server own root certificate. How can I make pip to behave the same way in the virtual environment as in the base environment?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using venv, when you already have conda?

Comment: what to have all files in a sperate folder structure, not nested in the install folder of conda, as explained in [The Definitive Guide to Conda Environments | by Matthew Sarmiento | Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-conda-environments-bc6180fc533). In addition `Changed in version 3.5: The use of venv is now recommended for creating virtual environments.`, see [venv — Creation of virtual environments — Python 3.9.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing openssl from this https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: I installed the package `pyOpenSSL` what added `conda-env\Lib\site-packages\OpenSSL`, what did not help. Installing Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1i Light
helped whyever? Any idea why I need to install it explicitly when the base environment works without it?