# Activating venv and conda environment at the same time

Tags: python, conda, environment, python-venv, virtual-environment

I am a beginner and was "playing around" with environments a bit. I came across a situation where it seemed that I had two environments activated:
I create a directory, create an environment with venv, activate it and then also conda activate a conda environment which I created before. These are the commands:

```
mkdir dummie_directory
cd dummie_directory
python -m venv .
Scripts\activate
conda activate old_env
```

After this the beginning of my command line looks like this:

```
(old_env)(dummie_directory) C:\Users\....
```

Does this mean that both environments are active?
Is there any intended use for this or will it most likely lead to some kind of clash/conflict between the installed packages?

Thanks

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64207964

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it does not mean they are both activated. Only one can have priority in the PATH, which is what I’d consider the simplest definition  of what “activated” means, functionally. The indicators in the PS1 string (i.e., the shell’s prompt string) are not robustly managed. The two environment managers are simply unaware of each other, and the string is only manipulated when an `activate` or `deactivate` procedure is called. There isn’t any dynamic monitoring that a particular environment is remaining active.

I wouldn’t rely on any behavior you observe in this state. It does not have a defined specification and is not intended to be used like this.

Comment: If it runs a `pip install`, in which environment will the lib be installed, venv or conda?

Comment: @ricgrego check with `which pip` (I wouldn't make any assumption about consistency of behavior).

Comment: Thanks, @merv !
I learned recently that using the 'conda deactivate' command deactivates Conda, including 'base'. Consequently, no installations will occur in any Conda environment

Answer (score 1):

I would add that the only difference it makes from just activating the last environment is that when the last environment is deactivated the first one is again reactivated. So, it uses a first-in-first-out logic to activate environments.