# How to make pip install stuff for another version of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, version

I had a working setup where I'd type `pip install some-library` and then I could import it into my projects. Then I decided to install miniconda which installed another version of python (3.8) that my system started defaulting to.

By running this command in terminal (I'm on a mac): `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3` I managed to revert so that when I type `python [something]`, my system uses the python located there (not the newly created one).
It seems that it's not as straightforward to get pip to do the same though. `pip install some-library` just installs stuff for the wrong python version.

How can one make `pip install some-library` install `some-library` to the python version located in /usr/local/bin/python3?

Comment: Have you tried `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip some-library` ?

Comment: @Philippe should be write.

`<path_to_your_python>/python -m pip` is the way to go.

In windows this is also what you should do if you want to update pip without provoking an error message:
`<path_to_your_python>/python -m pip install -U pip`

Comment: Yeah, @Philippe, that works, but I want to be able to use the shorter "pip install some-library" command instead. =)

Comment: Then you need to identify the `pip` which goes with `/usr/local/bin/python3`.
maybe `/usr/local/bin/pip3` or `/usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: @Philippe, what do you mean? both pip and pip3 points to the python 3.8 version located in: /Users/Henrik/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pip3 install some-library` for python 3. I hope that works fine!

Comment: @Henrik what result did you get? Let me know if it worked for you! : )

Comment: Unfortunately not. pip3 refers to the same python (3.8). I can also confirm this by the  return message from "pip3 -V".

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

In /usr/local/bin, I put an alias named "pip" that points to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3.6

Then i ran the following in terminal:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

It seems conda kept resetting this whenever I opened terminal.
Inspiration from this thread: [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default)

Comment: It works for now, but I'll hold off a few days until I mark it as accepted solution.