# npm run start error anaconda:environmental variable ubuntu20.04 :Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu

Tags: linux, npm, anaconda, environment-variables, npm-start

#### When I start run npm start, there is error like this.

## [npm error screen]

[image]

## [Debug_log]

debug log is like this

[image]

## [npm version & node version]

[image]

This is my node version and npm version.

## [path]

This is PATH.
[image]

## [HOST]

This is HOST.

[image]

---

### I think it's an environmental variable error.

But I don't know what else to try. Please help me.

---

### [The way in which I tried and failed]

### [1.conda install gxx_linux-64(Fail)]

[image]

---

### [2.change hostname using hostnamectl: fail]

[image]

### 2021.04.04 edit:
[3.execute source. etc/bash.bashrc](partial success:the reason I don't know)

### [edit bash.bashrc: HOST="localhost"]Failed

[image]

### [excute running server]

### excute source .bash.bashrc  web server running. But exit bash.bashrc, there is still same error

[image]

Comment: Try changing the hostname to something simpler with hostnamectl

Comment: Substitute text for all images so others might find your problem!

Comment: @RamanSailopal  Thanks for comment. I try change hostname(hy1-g3-3579 -> seong) but there is no change.

Comment: @Roadowl Thank your opionion.I edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution but I don't know Why this is work

**reference**

[According to Adriaan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default)

(base) is Anaconda's default environment.

When you connect to the CLI environment, the base starts active.

If (base) is active,

So We're going to turn off **automatic activation** of this virtual environment.

Running **$ conda config --set auto_activate_base false**

Then the front part that "(base) is disappeared.

If you open a new terminal and operate the server again, the server will work.

### [(base) dissapear & Server is running]

[Running command: $ conda config --set auto_activate_base false]

You can see what appears  **auto_activate_base: false**
below the **.condarc**

[image]

[image]