# Pip is using wrong path on macOS

Tags: python, macos, pip, anaconda

pip is installing packages into wrong path (/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip), since I don't want to use anaconda as my interpreter, how can I change it? I am using macos.

Comment: Maybe you want to disable Conda auto-activation? Possible duplicate then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't want Conda to be the default Python in the system. In that case, read [instructions to disable auto-activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default). Otherwise, one can always explicitly use a particular interpreter with the syntax:

```bash
/path/to/my/python -m pip install pkgname
```