# Conda environment doubly activated

Tags: conda

When I started the terminal before, I used to have a default conda environment to be activated. However, I somehow got two environments activated, as shown below (honestly, I'm not even sure this indicates two envs are activated). Can someone explain how this works and how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Try cleaning up your `.bashrc` (or similar) file. One can sometimes get away with `conda init --reverse` and then `conda init`, but if you've messed around with the initialization code, the `--reverse` mode may not work.

Comment: Also, note that seeing multiple `(env)` in your PS1 simply indicates that the prompt is messed up - I wouldn't assume that there is "double activation" (if that even makes sense) without actually inspecting PATH. The synchronization between activation and PS1 indicator is not robust.

Answer (score 0):

I once also had this problem so I had to `conda deactivate` twice (to deactivate both the environments that were activated) and then `conda activate xx`(to activate the environment I was actually using).
But later I realized that it was because conda was activating base environment by default for me. I checked out [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default) and this solved my problem:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Hope this helps!