# miniconda3: ImportError: No module named conda.cli

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

Some updates broke my `conda` installation...

`conda install`

now returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/francoiskroll/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ImportError: No module named conda.cli
```

**Extra details**

Not a duplicate of [After Anaconda installation, conda command fails with "ImportError: no module named conda.cli"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825250/after-anaconda-installation-conda-command-fails-with-importerror-no-module-na)

as I have an entry for conda in my `PATH` already:

```
echo $PATH
```

returns

```
/Users/francoiskroll/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/Users/francoiskroll/packages/guppy/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

It sounds like it may be a Python problem?

When I fire up python, it looks like:

`python`

```
Python 2.7.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 27 2019, 20:44:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
```

But I think I used to do `pythonw` to fire up python, if ever that helps!

Can you help?

Comment: Other possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54546450/570918 Also, note that it is no longer recommended to have `conda` on `PATH` like that other answer suggested (see [v4.4 release notes](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not an optimal answer, but I solved the issue by re-installing completely `miniconda3` (I am on macOSX).

I uninstalled `miniconda3` by removing the folder with

`rm -r ~/miniconda3/`

And resinstalled it: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html#install-macos-silent