# How to fix 'ModuleNotFoundError' for conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am unable to use `conda` commands after upgrading from Python 3.6 to Python 3.7. For example, when I wanted to see the active environment using `conda env list`, I get the following  error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "$HOME/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

The same error appears for all `conda` commands.

Running `python` shows:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
```

When I check the system path for Python 3.7 at `$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`, I don't find the `conda` directories but I find the same in the older Python version which I was previously using: `$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda`.

I thought to perform a clean uninstall and install of Anaconda starting with `anaconda-clean`. But I get the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/io.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "$HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/abc.py", line 147
print(f"Class: {cls.__module__}.{cls.__qualname__}", file=file)
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is there a way I can fix these issues? Thanks.

Comment: every python's version has own folder for modules and `anaconda` may do the same. You may have to install new conda for Python3.7 - https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After Anaconda installation, conda command fails with "ImportError: no module named conda.cli"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825250/after-anaconda-installation-conda-command-fails-with-importerror-no-module-na)