# Module not found on git bash conda environment

Tags: python, conda, git-bash

I have been running a module on my windows machine for quite awhile now and it has not been giving me any problems. I usually run it via the following command on my git bash terminal

```
conda activate condaenv
python -m modulename
```

Today I got the following error

```
C:\Users\user\Miniconda3\envs\condaenv\python.exe: No module named modulename/
```

Additionally, when I run any conda environment `python` in the git bash terminal, it just hangs.
Using `winpty python` as suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash) works. But when I try `winpty python -m modulename` I get the same error as before.

I am able to run the module without any problems with the same commands from the windows command prompt.

How do I go about troubleshooting this? It is crucial that I use git bash as I am using a few bash tools in my module.

Comment: Would one of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/19825250/6309 help?

Comment: I don't think path is an issue, my conda commands all seem to work fine

Comment: On a side note, I was able to side step git bash and use the windows command prompt by copying the bash tools (and most importantly their dependencies) from `/usr/bin` to my application, and point windows to use the bash commands within the application. To find out what are the dependencies each bash tool requires, utilise `ldd /usr/bin/<bash tool>` with git bash terminal. Note some bash tools like `rsync` requires other bash tools (in this case `ssh`)