# Miniconda3 returns nothing: both 'where conda' and 'conda' commands

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

I'm on a 64 bit Windows 11 computer with python 3.11.5 attempting to get miniconda3 working. I have installed miniconda as well as other python workspaces before and I attempted to uninstall all of them so I can have a clean start. My current issue is that despite having <C:\Users{USER}\miniconda3\Scripts> added to my PATH variable, the conda command is returning the following.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users{USER}\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 11, in 
> from conda.cli import main
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'

I've seen this error documented before so I tried the command 'where conda' which returned:

> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

I have tried adding the Scripts directory to PATH in environment variables, and uninstalling and re-installing both python and miniconda.

I'm not sure how to proceed so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks so much!

Comment: "I have tried adding the Scripts directory to PATH in environment variables, and uninstalling and re-installing both python and miniconda" You've done so much here its very hard to know where you are now. First of all, are you trying to install Anaconda or Miniconda? Secondly, what instructions did you follow ... or, in short, what did you actually do (not the whole history of your last 100 attempts ... the one that describes where you are now). Also if you btw happen to look at and follow the recommendations from official *conda documentation ... they don't recommend editing your PATH!

Comment: I am attempting to install miniconda. I currently have no references to conda in my PATH, and have Miniconda located in /users/{USER}/miniconda3. I understand that the documentation recommends against editing PATH, I simply saw others having my issue say that editing PATH fixed it.

Comment: Here are some specific instructions I found when just googling your error message: https://saturncloud.io/blog/solving-the-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-conda-in-anaconda/ and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825250/after-anaconda-installation-conda-command-fails-with-importerror-no-module-na

Comment: I have seen both these, sorry for not linking them earlier. Both of them suggest editing your PATH as a solution. The second also suggests a clean install of miniconda, which I have already tried. When working through the first one, I am unable to complete step one, as 'conda --version' returns the same "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'" error.

Comment: `ModuleNotFound: no module named conda` is exactly the problem described (and solved) in the first link, as well as given solutions in the second. So saying that's the error you get and therefore you cannot use these links makes no sense. Try to give more details. When you edit your path - how exactly do you edit your path? When you reinstall conda - what instructions do you follow? What configuration options do you choose? When you say it doesn't work - are you using a terminal? which one? Are you working in a python environment, or not? Are you installing as an adminstrator, or not? etc. etc